# Matching two noisy / lossy versions of the same data stream to each other

Tags: subsequences, streaming-algorithm

Say I have two noisy / lossy streams of symbols of the same data. Essentially, I want to match up the two streams as best as possible. For example, say I have:

```
s1 = 1 2 6 3 8 0 4 3 2 7 6 2 ...

s2 = 1 2 3 6 3 9 3 2 7 6 2 ...
```

and I'm essentially trying to end up with this:

```
s1 = 1 2   6 3 8 0 4 3 2 7 6 2 ...
     | |   | |       | | | | |
s2 = 1 2 3 6 3 9     3 2 7 6 2 ...
```

This feels like the kind of problem for which a well-known algorithm was invented in the 60s that's a household name with whoever knows what it is or something. But I haven't been able to find it, possibly because I don't know how to express the problem other than by my example above.

Any help or pointers to what such an algorithm might be -- or even what the problem is called so I could research it myself -- would be wonderful :)

Comment: Looks a lot like [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance). See also [sequence alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment).

Answer (score 3):

[Sequence Alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) is exactly what I was looking for -- thank you @Yuval Filmus!

This is commonly used in Genetics to line up genes, etc. Best I can understand, these typically require a fixed alphabet which I don't have, which means I can't do it as a stream. But if I give up on trying to do it as a stream and just collect both streams in their entirety before beginning, I can construct my alphabet by just observing what symbols appear in each stream before beginning.

A handy Python package which implements this out of the box is [python-alignment](https://github.com/eseraygun/python-alignment).

Comment: Wouldnt all unicode letters suffice as an alphabet?